# Add time in minutes to unix timestamp?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Add minutes in unix time stamp and then convert it into NSDate. I want to convert unix time stamp in minutes and than add my times in minutes to calculate correct time.

Comment: unix timestamps are integers. `new_ts = old_ts + (minutes * 60)`...

Comment: I'd prefer _convert unix timestamp to NSDate and add minutes_ or even _Add minutes to NSDate timestamp_ ;-)

Comment: @vadian if you want to go so far you might as well use `NSCalendar` to do it properly.

Comment: I didn't want to go that far ;-)

Comment: Thanks for answering i am adding seconds in timestamp and converting it into again NSDate but i am getting wrong result 
    NSTimeInterval _interval=timeStamp;
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

Comment: solved my problem not converting time stamp in milli second